# react_toastify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.toast.configure is not a function

Tags: reactjs, toast

I'm trying to add toast notifications to my project. For some reason after adding

```js
toast.configure();
```

code is not working and I have error:

```js
react_toastify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.toast.configure is not a function
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ3Ou.png)

Here is my code:

```js
import {toast} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

toast.configure();

function App() {


return(
<div>
if(error){
toast.error("error message...!"); 
}
<div>
)
}
```

Why am I getting this error? I have installed toast-notifications.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version (9), toast.configure is removed because  ["It does not work with react context because it creates a new react tree."](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/migration-v9#toastconfigure-removal)

You can add ToastContainer at the top of the document to fix this.

```
<ToastContainer
    autoClose={5000}
    hideProgressBar={true}
    {...otherPropsFromToastConfigure}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

New version just came out. Try to install `React Toastify` by adding a specific version. In my case, `8.2.0` works.

```
- npm i react-toastify@8.2.0
- yarn add react-toastify@8.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the toast.configure()

add  after the if statement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).